# Why after onclick action <i> fontawesome disappears

Tags: jquery, onclick

```
<ul>
  <li class="lfi93uf23"><a class="fedde390d" title="LIKE!"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 625</a></li>
  <li class="v4da7hf3s"><a class="q0fb5ba04" title="DISLIKE!"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> 365</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

```
$('.lfi93uf23').one('click', function(){
        var checkDown = $('.fedde390d').text();
        $('.fedde390d').text(+checkDown + 1);
        $('i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-down').css({'color':'#B4B4B4'});
        $('.q0fb5ba04').css({'color':'#B4B4B4'});
        $('.v4da7hf3s').unbind('click');
    });

    $('.v4da7hf3s').one('click', function(){
        var checkDown = $('.q0fb5ba04').text();
        $('.q0fb5ba04').text(+checkDown + 1);
        $('i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-up').css({'color':'#B4B4B4'});
        $('.fedde390d').css({'color':'#B4B4B4'});
        $('.lfi93uf23').unbind('click');
    });
```

Why after onclic action  fontawesome disappears. I see only amount likes\dislikes without icon

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so what is happening, is that inside the click handlers, when the count is updated:

```
$('.q0fb5ba04').text(+checkDown + 1);
```

that clobbers the HMTL within the same area where the icon and the count value are *both* present, which makes the icon disappear when the value updates.

To keep the icon present, I moved the icon out before the `<a>` tag so that it won't get clobbered when the count value is updated.

Note the I used `&nbsp;` to keep a space between the icon and the count value, but some other styling could be applied as well. (the change is only to the HTML for the icon move, no other changes)

Try the runnable example below.

```js
$('.lfi93uf23').one('click', function(){
    var checkDown = $('.fedde390d').text();
    $('.fedde390d').text(+checkDown + 1);
    $('i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-down').css({'color':'#B4B4B4'});
    $('.q0fb5ba04').css({'color':'#B4B4B4'});
    $('.v4da7hf3s').unbind('click');
});

$('.v4da7hf3s').one('click', function(){
    var checkDown = $('.q0fb5ba04').text();
    $('.q0fb5ba04').text(+checkDown + 1);
    $('i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-up').css({'color':'#B4B4B4'});
    $('.fedde390d').css({'color':'#B4B4B4'});
    $('.lfi93uf23').unbind('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
  <li class="lfi93uf23"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>&nbsp;<a class="fedde390d" title="LIKE!">625</a></li>
  <li class="v4da7hf3s"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>&nbsp;<a class="q0fb5ba04" title="DISLIKE!">365</a></li>
</ul>
```